# Using Keycloak with Spring Security on top of a custom authentication system?

Tags: spring, spring-security, keycloak, openid-connect

Here's my problem : I'm currently working on an app that has a custom authentication system made by other developers. Here's a quick look at it :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "/login";
    @Autowired
    private LoginProvider loginProvider;

    @Autowired
    private CredentialsAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    public WebSecurityConfig() {
        SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // Disable CSRF but protecting from XSS attacks (cross site scripting)
        http.csrf().disable();
        http
                .headers()
                .xssProtection()
                .and()
                .contentSecurityPolicy("script-src 'self'");

        // No session will be created or used by spring security
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        // Entry points
        http.authorizeRequests()//
                .antMatchers("/authentication/**").permitAll()//
                .antMatchers("/register/**").permitAll()//
                .antMatchers("/invitation/**").permitAll()//
                .antMatchers("/password/*/change/*").permitAll()//
                .antMatchers("/password/reset").permitAll()//
                .antMatchers("/company/**").permitAll()//
                .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()//
                .antMatchers("/zapier/**").permitAll()//
                .antMatchers("/redirect/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/simple-captcha-endpoint/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/core/**").access("hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1') or hasIpAddress('31.170.8.2') or hasIpAddress('31.170.8.3')")

                // Disallow everything else..
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()//

                // If a user try to access a resource without having enough permissions
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler);

        // Apply API key
        http.apply(new LoginFilterConfigurer(loginProvider));

        // disable page caching
        http.headers().cacheControl();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        // Allow swagger to be accessed without authentication
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs")//
                .antMatchers("/swagger-resources/**")//
                .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html")//
                // .antMatchers("/configuration/**")//
                .antMatchers("/webjars/**")//
                .antMatchers("/public");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class LoginProvider {

    @Autowired
    protected UiTokenRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    protected UiLoginRepository loginRepository;

    @Autowired
    protected OrganisationRepository organisationRepository;

    @Autowired
    protected WarningRepository warningRepository;

    @Autowired
    protected TrustabilityRepository trustabilityRepository;

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(LoginProvider.class);

    public Authentication getAuthentication(final UiToken authorisation) {

        Login login = authorisation.getLogin();
        if (login != null) {
            final String name = login.getName();
            final String usernameOrEmail = name == null || name.trim().isEmpty() ? login.getEmail() : name;

            final CustomCredentialDetails userDetails = new CustomCredentialDetails(login,usernameOrEmail);
            UiUser uiUser;
            try{
                uiUser = new UiUser(
                        usernameOrEmail,
                        userDetails.getPassword(),
                        userDetails.isEnabled(),
                        userDetails.isAccountNonExpired(),
                        userDetails.isCredentialsNonExpired(),
                        userDetails.isAccountNonLocked(),
                        userDetails.getAuthorities(),
                        login
                );
            }catch (IllegalArgumentException exception){
                log.warn("Troubles with loginId={} and name={}",login.getUuid(), usernameOrEmail, exception);
                return null;
            }
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(uiUser, "", uiUser.getAuthorities());
        }

        return null;
    }

    public String resolveApiKey(final HttpServletRequest req) {
        return req.getHeader("X-Auth-Token");
    }

    public UiToken findByAccessToken(final String token) {
        final String encryptedToken = UIRestTools.fixedEncrypt(token);
        return repository.findByTokenValueAndFetchUserAndFetchRoles(encryptedToken);
    }

    public void refreshToken(final UiToken authorisation) {
        authorisation.refreshToken();
        repository.save(authorisation);

        final Login login = authorisation.getLogin();
        login.setLastUseDate(new Date());
        loginRepository.save(login);
    }

}
```

```
public class LoginFilterConfigurer extends SecurityConfigurerAdapter<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity> {

    private final LoginProvider loginProvider;

    public LoginFilterConfigurer(final LoginProvider loginProvider) {
        this.loginProvider = loginProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        final LoginFilter customFilter = new LoginFilter(loginProvider);
        http.addFilterBefore(customFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

}
```

```
public class LoginFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    private final LoginProvider provider;

    public LoginFilter(final LoginProvider provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest req, final ServletResponse res, final FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {


        final String token = provider.resolveApiKey((HttpServletRequest) req);
        if (token != null) {
            final UiToken authorisation = provider.findByAccessToken(token);
            if (authorisation != null && !authorisation.isTokenExpired() && authorisation.getState().equals(UiTokenStateEnum.ACTIVATED)) {
                provider.refreshToken(authorisation);
                final Authentication auth = provider.getAuthentication(authorisation);
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

}
```

**Login** is a custom object that holds information about the user.
Right now in our app, users can create an account that is stored in the table *Login*. They connect to the app using that account, and the custom authentication system using the LoginFilter etc ... handles everything.

Here's the thing : one of our clients wants to use Keycloak to connect to the app because they have an Azure AD registry with their own users in it. My question is this one : is there anyway to have two separate authentication flows in the app ?
One would use what I posted above, allowing other clients to use our custom authentication system to connect, and we would have another system that would allow people to connect through Keycloak.

I feel like that's impossible and Spring Security only allows for one type of authentication but I cannot be sure.
Alternatively, would it be possible for the Azure AD users to authenticate using Keycloak, then we could just retrieve the token, store it in the Login object and customize our existing flow to add specific Keycloak logout etc ...
I'm not sure if that makes sense, I'm quite new to Spring Security and Keycloak as well.

Thanks for any help you can provide !
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think it mighy be doable, not clean / safe / maintainable.. but doable..

I would suggest to read this part of doc : [Mutli-tenant Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_multi_tenancy)

This will allow you to catch incoming request, select which one will go for Keycloak auth or your custom auth system. You can base the selection by url parsing, header etc..

But you should be very carful here of what your doing.

Another option would be two instances of your app, with two different urls and two different authentication process..

For AD users you can check for [user federation](https://For%20AD%20users%20you%20can%20check%20for%20user%20federation%20:%20https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_user-storage-federation).
Hope it helps
++